# Get current time in Javascript without creating Date object?

Tags: javascript, date, garbage-collection

I implement custom double/triple/other clicks in my javascript app, but I'm concerned with garbage-collection pauses. Is there a way to obtain current time with milisecond precision *without* creating Date object? Some method to reset the existing Date object to current time?

Comment: you said, **reset** the existing Date object, **reset** might overwrite the existing value.

If you're ok with that, then you can simply do `old_date_object = new Date();`

Comment: that changes the date object the reference points to, it does not change the old date object.

Comment: In my old code I was creating new Date objects, but as I've read somewhere, creating and dropping objects too often may trigger long GC pauses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [Date.now()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now)

> The now() method returns the milliseconds elapsed since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC up until now as a number.

you can use this as a fallback for older browsers

```
if (!Date.now) {
    Date.now = function now() {
    return +(new Date);
  };
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I've looked for! Heh, w3schools do not mention that method...

Comment: @AlW A good thing to do is not rely on w3schools. They are good for very basic things, but often leave out important things or are just wrong. Just stick to MDN